# VScode python 3 pylint: I can import X file in A but not B

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm using the latest version of VScode, using pylint and python 3. I'm using I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and virtualenv. I can import all python and pip packages correctly, I only face the error when working with files I created.

I have 3 files, all are next to each other sitting in the same folder. `a.py`, `b.py` and `keys.py`, the latter contains nothing but keys as strings.

in `a.py`, I can do

`from keys import X`

But in `b.py` pylint doesn't let me do that, I get

`Unable to import 'keys' [E0401]`

I can only do

`from .keys import X`

Which is wrong but I mean that would remove the error above.

Comment: This was also reported in https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3874 and resolved there.

Comment: @BrettCannon Would you like to leave an answer here so that I could close the question and upvote your answer?

Comment: @lyonb Sure! It helps me keep track of which questions don't need an answer anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Pylint is seeing the files as contained in a package (hence the relative import of `from .keys import X` working). Trying to execute `a.py` directly is kind of "cheating" by trying to view the files as not in a package.